# Taylor expansion of $x^{1/x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am new to Taylor expansions and I would like to calculate the Taylor polynomial of the function $x^{1/x}=e^{(1/x)\log x}$. Since the function is not defined at $x=0$, how should I choose the point which I will calculate the expansion at? I would like to understand the following result

$$x^{1/x}=1-\frac1x \log\frac1x+O(x^{-2})\qquad (1)$$

The first derivative of my function is $$f'(x)=x^{1/x-2}\cdot(1-\log x)$$
Given that the Taylor polynomial is $f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\cdots$, I can't get how this first derivative is used in $(1)$. For which $a$ is $(1)$ calculated? Moreover, why I cannot obtain the same first two terms using the derivative?

Should I use the Taylor expansion of $e^u$ substituting $u$ with my $u(x)$? Is this possible? Anyway, I should obtain the same result in every situation.

Could you please guide me to understand these points? What's my problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your formula makes no sense. What is $n$?

Comment: Good. Now: what makes you think the question has anything to do with Taylor expansions?

Comment: Actually, Taylor expansions can be useful here: write $$x^{1/x}=e^{(1/x)\log x}$$ first.

Comment: @Gerry This is a spin-off question. I am trying to understand the answer to a question I posted some time ago http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925006/is-n1-n-1-in-on-frac12-as-n-to-infty

Comment: Anyway I was trying to get the taylor expansion of $$e^{(1/x)\log x}$$ What am I misunderstanding @Gerry?

Comment: I assume you know the Taylor expansion of $e^u$ as a function of $u$. Just replace $u$ everywhere with $(1/x)\log x$.

Comment: @Gerry: but that would give error term $O(\log(x) / x^2)$. But I actually suspect the claimed equation is not true.

Comment: @hurkyl See this link http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%281%2Fx%29+taylor+exp It suggests it is a series expansion at $x=\infty$ and see also the spin-off question (comment above).

Comment: You have to decide once and for all the point around which you seek an expansion of the function. When $x\to\infty$, your (1) "almost" holds since $\log x/x\to0$ and $e^u=1+u+\Theta(u^2)$ hence $x^{1/x}=1+\log x/x+\Theta((\log x)^2/x^2)$. Thus, in (1), the main term $1+\log x/x$ is correct but the remainder term $O(1/x^2)$ is wrong. The expansion when $x\to0$ (which you mysteriously invoke in the question) is quite unrelated to (1) (and to the other question you link to, I must add).

Comment: @GerryMyerson. What you wrote is true only if $(\log x)/x\to0$ when $x\to x_0$. Unfortunately here, $x_0$ cannot be equal to $0$, the expansion has to be for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: When $x\to0$, we have $(\log x)/x\to-\infty$. Formula (1) can not be true for $x\to0$ because $x^{1/x}\to0$ when $x\to0$.

Comment: Guys, the spin-off question has been edited. Hence now, my question is nonsensical. I will soon edit it in order to clarify my doubts.